# In vtiger 7, is it possible to create a new user using webservice

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

Not able to create User record while using Webservice

I am try to use Vtiger webservice to create a new user. But when I fill in the field "roleid" it prompt me a error message.
Error Message: Create failed: Permission to perform the operation is denied for id

Any one have the solution for this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a describe action via webservice over module "Users" and see what value need to put in this field.

Other thing you can do is, retrieve a user present on vTiger and compare the field roleid with tour value.

Comment: For some reason, when printing out 'roleid', even if the user has a role, the 'roleid' still has no value in the print out. Since roleid is a mandatory field I don't think it's possible to create a user if that field is empty or is using a wrong input.